# How can I recover access to Google API Projects where the last owner was deleted

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-console

I've got a bit of an issue.  The last owner of a couple of API projects left my company and subsequently his google email account was deleted more than a month ago.  This has left us in a precarious state as we are unable to gain administrative access to the API project.

The API projects themselves still seem to be somewhat active as I am able to use some of their functionality, however they are disassociated from any administrative account (as far as I can tell).

I need to either regain control of these API projects or delete them so the old API credentials for them are no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason that for any project within a company should have more than one owner (and any employee's online accounts related to work should be looked at before the person leaves). Normally the project will get deleted after some time if the owner's account is deleted and there are no other owners.

Can you send me the client_id in those projects and the deleted owner's information, so we can have a look at the state? 
You can contact me through my G+ profile.

Comment: Unfortunately my company is not on G+. Is there any other way for me to get in touch with you on this. (email?)

Comment: You don't need the company to be on G+. You can send me email through gmail. See http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/reach-people-you-know-more-easily.html

Comment: @nvnagr are you still the best person to talk to about this? I emailed ~ a week ago.

Comment: Yes, I'm still the right person. We have made changes so this issue doesn't happen. In most cases, someone else in the same company has created a client_id with the same cert hash. Also check any deleted projects and check to see if there was a client_id in there with the same cert hash (and delete it first before deleting the project)

Comment: Hey, I got a similar problem. Owner was deleted, I still see the project in a list of projects but cannot open it because of 403. Are you by any chance still available for these issues?